# How is millimetre wave generated and why it cannot go higher to terahertz frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation, microwaves

I have been trying to find out how millimetre wave (3 GHz to 300 GHz) signals are generated but didn't find much. And I knew for some reason this method cannot generate THz electromagnetic waves, that is why people are using very complicated methods to make THz emitters. Does anyone have insights on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a system from ABmillimetre in Paris that **CAN** generate THz waves of high spectral purity via high harmonic generation of phase stabilized microwaves.  It's possible to get CW signals of up to a microwatt at 1 THz this way.  The harmonics are generated by diodes coupled to very precisely tuned cavities.  The fundamental microwaves are phase locked to (in my case) a Rb clock.  The dynamic range is extraordinary and the phase stability is unsurpassed by laser based systems.  I routinely work in the range from 300 - 600 Ghz.  It's pretty expensive for the waveguide and scalar horns (which are made to precisely cancel the cross polarization that results from coupling rectangular waveguides to circular horns).  I've built ultra high finesse cavities and near-field scanning systems based on this system.  It's quasi-optics, so you get the full amplitude and phase of the transmitted and reflected fields.  This is achieved by having a matching mixer on the receive end, so the THz signal gets mixed by several stages down to KHz, so you can use ultra deep A/D.  It is pretty easy to calibrate out the effects of sample holders for liquids or to look at the perturbations in the field induced by, say, shining a laser on a thin film.  I have even measured the complex conductivity of mono-atomic graphene at 500 GHz.  The band from about 700-1000 GHz can be covered by a single harmonic (in my case the 54th) of the fundamental microwave frequency.  Only the fundamental is transmitted/collected via coax.  Everything else propagates quasi-optically in waveguide or free space.  I can reference lots of my papers with examples, but just google Philippe Goy or ABmillimetre in Paris.  There is simply no comparison with TD methods.  And CW laser photomixing produces much less power and DR.

Added:  **If you don't care about phase** then the whole apparatus is MUCH simpler.  All you need is a basic microwave source, a harmonic multiplier and a diode detector.  The details of your experiment will dictate what sort of waveguide and horns you use.  But you can get going in W band pretty easily.  I get used components from Western Test Systems http://www.westerntestsystems.com/
But the higher the frequency the more expensive and complex since you may need to cascade amplifiers and multipliers.

Comment: As the OP pointed out: this is very complicated when compare with say an L-Band radar.

Comment: Not really.  All depends on how high a frequency you want to achieve.  Up to 100 Ghz is completely straightforward.  And the plumbing is readily available.  At 1 Thz it is no more complicated than laser based systems and far superior in terms of power and dynamic range.  And the OP was about getting to 1 THz.  It CAN be done and this is how you do it.  And, I should point out, there are now solid state amplifiers working in this range.  Also, if you don't care about phase, the complexity is dramatically reduced since you don't need harmonic mixers.

Comment: The history of the last 100 years RF shows that to get a hitherto unused frequency first all coherent generators use diode based harmonic multipliers starting from a stable source. There have been two main classes of these, in one the diode is used as a nonlinear resistor, in  the other the diode is back-biased and is used as a nonlinear capacitor; both schemes generate harmonics. 35 years ago the RF high tech was generating 100mW at 94GHz this way, today it is probably 940GHz and use transistors below 100GHz ...